# Moving result from 1:n query to repeating columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

I would like to achieve the following from a result of a 1:n join using T-sql

```
 Surname | Givename  |..Address  | City

Name1....| Givename1.|..Addr11...|  City11

Name1....| Givename1.|..Addr12...|  City12

Name2....| Givename2.|..Addr21...|  City21

Name2....| Givename2.|..Addr22...|  City22

Name2....| Givename2.|..Addr23...|  City23
```

TO:

```
Surname | Givename.. | Address | City... | Address | City... | Address | City

Name1....| Givename1...|  Addr11....| City11. | Addr12....| City12. |

Name2....| Givename2...|  Addr21....| City21. | Addr22....| City22. | Addr23....|  City23
```

I not care about repeating columnames. Up if there is a soultion with numbers in the repeating columns it would be fine too.

Thanks

In my opinion Pivot is not a solution in this case. Because the column name should repat, and in pivot, cell values are moved to column names, also is unlike pivot no aggregate function involved.

Comment: Google "SQL pivot query" to get started, and maybe [read this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query).

Comment: You have columns with the same name here, a column's name *should* be unique within the dataset. Your rows seem to also have variable number of columns; that isn't allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: Do you know how big *n* is?  If not you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: n is in praxis not more then 5. But i am looking for a dynamic solution, that would also work with undefined numeber of n.

Comment: I know you don't think this is a `PIVOT`, but _tons_ of `PIVOT`s include entirely useless `MIN()` or `MAX()` arguments that don't change the data in order to get the `PIVOT` functionality. And you're going to have to work a little harder at the column names, but all the same, this is a `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 0):

In my thought, the following query will handle your issue. However the SQL Server has **column number limit for tables**.

> Columns per table     1,024   Tables that include sparse column sets
>   include up to 30,000 columns. See sparse column sets.

You should take this considiration for your data.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##PivotUnlimited
CREATE TABLE  #Test(Surname  VARCHAR(100) , GivenName  VARCHAR(200),
Adress  VARCHAR(100),City  VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Test
VALUES
('Name1','Givename1','Addr11','City11'),
('Name1','Givename1','Addr12','City12'),
('Name2','Givename2','Addr21','City21'),
('Name2','Givename2','Addr22','City21'),
('Name2','Givename2','Addr23','City23')
,('Name5','Givename5','Addr51','City51'),
('Name5','Givename5','Addr52','City52'),
('Name5','Givename5','Addr53','City53'),
('Name5','Givename5','Addr54','City54'),
('Name3','Givename3','Addr31','City31')

DECLARE @Counter AS INT=1
DECLARE @Max AS INT
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Max= MAX(DetMax) FROM
 (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by Surname ORDER BY Surname ) AS DetMax FROM #Test
) AS TMP


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##PivotUnlimited
CREATE TABLE ##PivotUnlimited (Surname VARCHAR(100),GivenName VARCHAR(100))

WHILE @Counter <=@Max
BEGIN

SET @SQL= 'ALTER TABLE ##PivotUnlimited ADD  ADDR' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Counter) + ' VARCHAR(100)'
EXEC(@SQL)
SET @SQL= 'ALTER TABLE ##PivotUnlimited ADD  City' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Counter) + ' VARCHAR(100)'
EXEC(@SQL)
SET @Counter=@Counter+1
END


INSERT INTO ##PivotUnlimited (Surname,GivenName)
SELECT DISTINCT Surname , GivenName FROM #Test

DECLARE @Name AS VARCHAR(100) 

DECLARE cursorT CURSOR

FOR
SELECT DISTINCT Surname from #test

OPEN cursorT 
FETCH NEXT FROM cursorT INTO @Name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
          DECLARE @CounterCursor AS INT=1
          DECLARE @MaxCursort AS INT =0
          DECLARE @UpdateSQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
          DECLARE @UptAdr AS VARCHAR(100)
          DECLARE @UptCity AS VARCHAR(100)
            SELECT @MaxCursort=RowNumber FROM (
          SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by Surname ORDER BY Surname ) AS RowNumber FROM #Test  
           WHERE  Surname=@Name
          ) AS TMP_TBL


          WHILE @CounterCursor<= @MaxCursort
          BEGIN
          SELECT @UptAdr=Adress ,@UptCity=City  FROM (
          SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by Surname ORDER BY Surname ) AS RowNumber,* FROM #Test  
          ) AS TMP_TBL WHERE RowNumber=@CounterCursor and Surname=@Name

         SET @UpdateSQL= 'UPDATE ##PivotUnlimited SET ADDR' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@CounterCursor) + ' = '  + '''' + @UptAdr +'''' + ' , ' 
         + ' City' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@CounterCursor) + ' = '  + '''' + @UptCity +'''' +  ' WHERE Surname = ' + '''' + @Name + ''''
         EXEC (@UpdateSQL)
         SET @CounterCursor=@CounterCursor+1

         END

          FETCH NEXT FROM cursorT INTO @Name
END
CLOSE cursorT 
DEALLOCATE cursorT 

SELECT * FROM ##PivotUnlimited

+---------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Surname | GivenName | ADDR1  | City1  | ADDR2  | City2  | ADDR3  | City3  | ADDR4  | City4  |
+---------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Name1   | Givename1 | Addr11 | City11 | Addr12 | City12 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
| Name2   | Givename2 | Addr21 | City21 | Addr22 | City21 | Addr23 | City23 | NULL   | NULL   |
| Name3   | Givename3 | Addr31 | City31 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
| Name5   | Givename5 | Addr51 | City51 | Addr52 | City52 | Addr53 | City53 | Addr54 | City54 |
+---------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```